# Update data for only 1 user. (NodeJS, ExpressJS, MySQL)

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

I tried to create a form that let users change their name and password, unfortunately I ran into a syntax error.

You can see my code and the error message below.

```
// Multiple '?' not working, SQL syntax error
db.query('UPDATE users SET name = ?, password = ? WHERE email = ?', { name: newName, password: hashedNewPassword, email: email }, (error, results) => {
   console.log(results);
   if(error) {
      console.log(error);
   } else {
      res.status(200).redirect("/");
   }
})
```

code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? WHERE `email`= ?' at line 1",

Comment: You are passing an object for the values, shouldn't it be an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use [mariadb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb) package I believe your syntax should be

```
db.query('UPDATE users SET name = ?, password = ? WHERE email = ?', [newName, hashedNewPassword, email]...
```

ie. replacement values should be an array in the same order as `?`.